# How to make calendar block show site events?

Tags: blocks, datetime

I have a website in which I use the Calendar module in combination with a content type I created. While I manage to achieve the calendar page to show up the events in their dates, how can I make the same for the calendar block? For example when an event has a "from date" of 20 August, I want the calendar block to have that 20 August date as a link to the event.

Comment: If you have achieved this for your page display already, can't you use the same view format and settings for your block display to get the same functionality?  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you probably want to use the views module to create a custom block that contain the calendar items.  Here is an example...

http://drupal.org/node/1250714